# prove using the definition of connectedness and paths that $G_3 = (V_1\cup V_2, E_1\cup E_2)$ is a connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

Let $ G_1 = (V_1, E_1), G_2 = (V_2, E_2)$ such that...

- G1 is connected
- G2 is connected
- $V_1\cap V_2={v_o}$

I know since the intersection of both vertex sets only contains a single vertex, implying any path including vertices from $G_1$ and $G_2$ will not include duplicates. How do I formalize this notion to show every vertex in $G_3$ is connected to every other vertex (i.e.: there exists a path between every other vertex).

Comment: For a vertex $u$ and $w$ in $G_3$, if both vertices are in $G_1$ or both are in $G_2$, then this is obvious. If $u$ is in $G_1$ and $w$ in $G_2$, there is a path joining $u$ and $v$ in $G_1$ and a path joining $v$ and $w$ in $G_2$ so there is a path joining $u$ and $w$ in $G_3$ via $v$.

Comment: you used union instead of intersection for the third constraint.

Comment: @mathpadawan fixed!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that the graph on the respective unions of the vertex and edge sets of two connected graphs with exactly one common vertex is also connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159468/prove-that-the-graph-on-the-respective-unions-of-the-vertex-and-edge-sets-of-two)

Answer (score 1):

Let $u$ and $v$ in $V_3=V_1 \cup V_2$. If $u,v$ are both in $V_1$, then there is a path from $u$ to $v$ in $(V_1,E_1)$ and this is still a path from $u$ to $v$ in $(V_3,E_3)$ (as $E_1 \subseteq E_3$).

If $u,v$ are both in $V_2$, mutatis mutandis the same argument applies in $(V_2,E_2)$.

Finally we have (WLOG) $u \in V_1$, $v \in V_2$. 
Then there is a path from $u$ to $v_0$ in $(V_1,E_1)$ and a path from $v_0$ to $v$ in $(V_2,E_2)$. Combining these paths we have a path in $(V_3,E_3)$ from $u$ to $v$.

Comment: If  the intersection between both vertice sets had more than 1 vertex, how would this proof change? Would you take into account for duplicates?

Comment: @neet no, then you can pick any vertex of intersection you like.

Comment: @neet Recall that the person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted". See https://math.stackexchange.com/tour